# Correct IF indentation with PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, indentation, logical-operators

I didn't find any Coding style guide to answer my question. I have a simple IF with nested braces and several logic operators. How should I indent this:

```
if (
  !$var
  || (
    $this->var != $this->needed_var()
    && !$this->another_func()
    && !$this->another_func_two()
  )
) {
  // My code...
}
```

I find it uggly... Any help ?

Comment: There's no real answer here. It is generally up to personal preference or an established team standard.  PHP, unlike some other languages, is light on conventions for stuff like this...

Comment: I think it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The PEAR coding standards [have useful things to say](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.control.php#standards.control.splitlongstatements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the [Zend Framework Coding Standards](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html).  They cover this particular case under "Control Statements" as follows:

```
if (($a == $b)
    && ($b == $c)
    || (Foo::CONST == $d)
) {
    $a = $d;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

To make it easier to read i would store the result of the longer statement into a meaningful variable.

```
$is_not_needed = ($this->var != $this->needed_var() && !$this->another_func() && !$this->another_func_two()); 

if( !$var || $is_not_needed ) 
{
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are no universal coding style rules, the most important thing is that you are consistent in your formatting and your code is readable. I'd format that like this, but it's only my coding style!

```
if (!$var || ($this->var != $this->needed_var() &&
              !$this->another_func() &&
              !$this->another_func_two())){
  // My code...
}
```

In any case you can check [pear](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/) for coding standards

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to PHP, but the QT Framework coding style and convention documents are really nicely written, and make a lot of coherent sense.

You can check it out here: http://wiki.qt-project.org/Coding_Style

Comment: I stopped reading at "Spaces, not tabs!" Idiots.

Comment: "always use a single space between the type and ‘*’ or ‘&’, but no space between the ‘*’ or ‘&’ and the variable name." FFS. I wish people would stop spreading harmful rubbish like this >.<

Comment: I guess that comes from being cross platform..? Shame you stopped reading! The rest is really quite good.

Comment: I did actually keep reading. The rest is basically what I do, except for the switch/case bit. What does cross-platform have to do with it?

Comment: Differing definitions of how many spaces tabs actually represent. I guess using spaces (even though I personally don't) gets around this.

Comment: I don't see how. All space-indentation does is disable the ability for a programmer to view indentation in their preferred way.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm with you. Using spaces is horrible on so many levels. If I were being forced to use spaces, then I'd probably setup a pre-commit hook to convert my tabs into spaces and just keep on like that.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the [WordPress Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards). Though most of these standards are the same.

Comment: I don't see anything related to `if` and several logical operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var_is_ok    = ($this->var != $this->needed_var());
$another_req  = ($this->another_func());
$another_req2 = ($this->another_func_two());

if (!$var || ($var_is_ok && !$another_req && !another_req2) )
{
  // My code...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you have a conditional for which there is no clear way to indent, the conditional is too long. Programmers won't be able to comprehend it quickly as it stands.

Refactor it.